# css: class that blends a color into existing background color?

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color

I have a table with rows of alternating colors, e.g.:

```
<table>
  <tr class="even"><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="even"><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <td></td><td></td></tr>  
</table>
```

I want to highlight a bunch of the table cells, but in a different way if the cell is in an even or an odd row, as multiple vertically-stacked cells might be highlighted and I want to maintain the alteration of row color. What I first came up with was to just create two classes, `highlight_even` and `highlight_odd`, figure out in my javascript code (as this highlighting will be done dynamically) whether the row is `even` or `odd`, and set `class` accordingly, e.g.:

```
<table>
  <tr class="even"><td></td><td class="highlight_even"></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <td></td><td class="highlight_odd"></td></tr>
  <tr class="even"><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <td></td><td></td class="highlight_odd"></tr>  
</table>
```

The colors are very straightforward, though. I want to make `highlight_even` by blending green into the `even` color, and `highlight_odd` by blending the same green into the `odd` color. Is there any way to accomplish that in css, such that that same highlighted table could just look like this?

```
<table>
  <tr class="even"><td></td><td class="highlight"></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <td></td><td class="highlight"></td></tr>
  <tr class="even"><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <td></td><td></td class="highlight"></tr>  
</table>
```

Something like (in pseudocode):

```
td.highlight {
    background-color: blend #ff0 into existing background-color;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blend", exactly?

Comment: Opacity might help, but it is not very well suported in old-ish browsers http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just define the blending manually?  You shouldn't need multiple `highlight_*` classes to do this, either.  Assuming even rows are #ff0 and odd rows are #f0f and a plain white highlight:

```
tr.even td.highlight { background: #ff8; }
tr.odd td.highlight { background: #f8f; }
```

Comment: I'm applying `highlight` to the `td`s, not the `tr`s.

Comment: ahh i forgot about child selectors. that's pretty good, that's basically just what i was doing manually with javascript

Answer (score 8):

Set the background-color of the highlight using rgba.

```
td.highlight {
    background-color: #ff0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

(Where 0.5 is the opacity.)

Or for a more granular progressive enhancement

```
.odd .highlight{
    background-color: /*blend of #ff0 and .odd;*/
}
.even .highlight{
    background-color: /*blend of #ff0 and .even;*/
}
.odd .highlight, .even.highlight{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Edited to address support for IE8-.

Comment: It makes sense to take into account that this is not supported by IE8 and older. For them, PNG-24 semitransparent background image can be used.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Good point.  I've edited to address IE8- support.

Comment: In the more granular solution you've added, why even bother with the half-opacity stuff when you're just going to do the math for the blending ahead of time?  The first option is probably how I would actually do this, unless management **really** wants the highlights to be blended in IE<9.

Comment: @Stuart Branham I agree, given colors only (which is all the original question required), but if anything more visually complex than a solid block of "highlight" color was wanted, I thought the granular would be a better approach.  So I threw one for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
td.highlight {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

This uses CSS3, so it won't work in older browsers. And you'll have to write rules for each browser (ie. `background-image: -moz-linear-gradient: ...`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can used without define class in table

now you can define in tr color even or odd properties

as like this

```
 <table>

    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This is one</td></tr>
</table>

tr:nth-child(odd) {background: red;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: green;}`
```

and now check to [live here](http://jsfiddle.net/n83K5/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/n83K5/1/